# Django form help_text best practices

Tags: python, django

we've got into an argument during a code review. Where is the best place to keep long form help text in a django project?

Situation: We need to add relatively long (about 320 characters) help texts to a field. For form rendering we are using ModelForm. For form rendering we are using bootstrap library.

**Opinion A**: Add it directly into an HTML template.

```
# template.html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="{{ form.field.id_for_label }}">{{ form.field.label }}</label>
    {{ form.field }}
    <span class="help-block">
        Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text.
    </span>
</div>
```

Pros:

1. It is better to keep long help_text inside html file, not .py
2. In the future we might want to add HTML tags, and it would be better to have it inside HTML file too.

**Option B**: Add it to the ModelForm's Meta.

```
# forms.py
help_texts = {
    'field': 'Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text Help text.'
}
# template.html
{% bootstrap_field form.field %}
```

Pros:

1. Field is autogenerated and not hardcoded.
2. In the future we can have HTML inside it too with `mark_safe()`.

What do you think about the options? Could you please share your opinion about the best way to handle help_text?

Answer (score -2):

IMHO this whole idea of "field auto-generation" is horrible. OK, some field properties come from the model, but *most* of them should be in the HTML itself.

The project [django-silhouette](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-silhouette) solves this problem very well and that's what I'm moving to on current projects.

As for the question itself, I'd put the help text inside the HTML, as a temporary solution until you fix the problem of repeating yourself in the HTML (which can be with the help django-silhouette or just shared HTML partials).

Comment: I think the idea of auto generation is great, if done correctly (i.e. works 90% of the time and allows easy overriding when it doesn't).